# how to filter from dictionary of dictionaries using angularjs

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

i want to filter from a dictionary of dictionaries using angularjs ng-repeat as follows

```
 var items = {car:{
                    "maruthi":800,"hyundai":1000,"polo":1500
        }
        bikes:{
                "maruthi":100,"hyundai":200,"polo":150
            }
        }
```

i want to obtain result object car and its value

i already tried like following:

```
<span ng-repeat="(k,v) in items | filter : "car" ">{{v.maruthi}}</span>
```

i want result as 800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
<span ng-repeat="(k,v) in items>
  <span ng-if="k=='car'">{{v.maruthi}}</span>
</span>
```